# Elasticsearch sorting by matching array item

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I have a following structure in indexed documents:

```
document1: "customLists":[{"id":8,"position":8},{"id":26,"position":2}]
document2: "customLists":[{"id":26,"position":1}]
document3: "customLists":[{"id":8,"position":1},{"id":26,"position":3}]
```

I am able to search matching documents that belong to a given list with match query "customLists.id = 26". But I need to sort the documents based on the position value within that list and ignore positions of the other lists.

So the expected results would be in order of document2, document1, document3

Is the data structure suitable for this kind of sorting and how to handle this?

Comment: What does `ignore positions of the other lists.` mean in your question?

Comment: if I search with customLists.id=26 I am only interested in position value in that item {"id":26,"position":5}

Comment: Not able to understand you .Please  share the sample output which you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to set mapping type of  `customLists` as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-nested-type.html) and then use sorting by [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html)

Example :

**1) Create Index & Mapping**

```
put test
put test/test/_mapping
{
   "properties": {
      "customLists": {
         "type": "nested",
         "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "integer"
            },
            "position": {
               "type": "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**2) Index Documents :**

```
    put test/test/1 
    {
     "customLists":[{"id":8,"position":8},{"id":26,"position":2}]
    }
    put test/test/2
    {
    "customLists":[{"id":26,"position":1}] 
    }

   put test/test/3
   {
      "customLists":[{"id":8,"position":1},{"id":26,"position":3}]
   }
```

**3) Query to sort by positon for given id**

```
post test/_search
    {
       "filter": {
          "nested": {
             "path": "customLists",
             "query": {
                "term": {
                   "customLists.id": {
                      "value": "26"
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "sort": [
          {
             "customLists.position": {
                "order": "asc",
                "mode": "min",
                "nested_filter": {
                   "term": {
                      "customLists.id": {
                         "value": "26"
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```